# Python combine threading and async

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I have a question. Are these functions ran in parallel when getting max? If not is it possible to make something like that parallel?

```
import asyncio
import threading

def do_sync(number: int) -> int:
    lock = threading.Lock()
    lock.acquire()

    result = number + 10

    lock.release()
    return result

async def do_async(number: int) -> int:
    result = number + 10
    return result

async def main():
    result = max(do_sync(1), await do_async(2))
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: No, both run in the same thread and only one function can run in the same thread at the same time. Async only allows to run a function while another function waits for some things in the same thread.

Comment: Possible solution: Run one function in a different thread (which is easier for `do_sync` but also possible for `do_async`). Additionally you would have to run both before calling `max` and somehow wait for them to return their results (e. g. using a `Future`) to feed it into `max`.

Comment: See arrmansa's answer.  If you're using Python >= 3.9 also look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=to_thread#asyncio.to_thread.  That function lets you easily run a sync function in another thread and await the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a sync function in parralel with an async function you will need to use multiple threads. You can either send the sync function to a a new thread with https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor or you can start an event loop on a different thread and schedule your async function on that loop with https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe and get a future that you can get the .result() of.